# How to install an update on a maintenance window using swupdate?

Tags: swupdate, eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I've configured a project with swupdate on a Raspberry Pi and hawkbit as the OTA update server.

My goal is to send updates in advance and have swupdate install them during a designated maintenance window. I noticed the "download only" option on hawkbit and am exploring how to initiate the update on the device specifically during the maintenance window. Currently, I'm considering setting up a cron job on the device to run a command similar to the following:

swupdate -v -i /path/to/file.swu -P "mount /dev/sda1 /boot" -p "umount /boot && reboot" -e "stable,sda3"

This command is intended to run the update, reboot and boot from the other partition. The problem now is that I can't find where swupdate stores the .swu files when setting "download only" option on hawkbit to be able to run this command.

Do some of you have any ideas on how to achieve this?